# problem in onClick action of textbox that doesnt work in firefox but work on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi my bellow code works on IE but doesnt work on latest version of FireFox.
my IE version is :11.483.15063 and my Firefox version is 64 .
i think that my problem because using parseInt that was not supported in FireFox

```
function setTabPage() {
                if (trvpnlState == 2) return;
                if (trvpnlState == 1)
                { HidePnl1(); return }
                var cntElm = document.all['frmContent'];
                var top = document.all['GroupTab1_0'].offsetTop;
                var left = document.all['GroupTab1_0'].offsetLeft;
                var tp1 = document.all['TabPage1'];
                tp1.style.width = 0;
                tp1.style.left = event.clientX - parseInt(tp1.style.width.split('px')) - event.offsetX + 170;

                var prnHlt = parseInt(document.all['GroupTab1_0'].parentElement.parentElement.style.height.split('px')[0]);
                tp1.style.top = 30;
                tp1.style.height = 700;
                tp1.style.display = "";

                if (trvpnlState == 0)
                    ShowPnl1();
            }

 function ShowPnl1() {
            if (oInterval != '') window.clearInterval(oInterval);
            oInterval = window.setInterval("ShowHide(1)", 1);
            document.all['TabPage1'].focus();
            trvpnlState = 2;
        }

        function HidePnl() {
            if ((trvpnlState != 1) && (event.srcElement.id == 'TabPage1')) return

            var divTabPage = document.all['TabPage1'];
            if (event.clientX > parseInt(divTabPage.style.left.split("px")[0]))
                return;

            HidePnl1();
        }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: you are sure https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `srcElement` is a non-standard IE specific property, use `event.target` instead.

Comment: ... And `document.all` ... just  d o n ' t  .  u s e  .  i t.